# Finding largest and smallest path length of tree directory Java

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, tree, directory-tree

I'm having trouble with a problem that deals with a directory tree and finding the smallest and largest path of length in that tree. The problem is this:

Given a string of directory and file names, where the number of "-" indicates the relationship between all of the directories (such as which files and directories are within a directory), find the smallest and largest path lengths.

For example, a string that has the following contents:

```
dir1
-file1
-file2
-innerDir1
--file11
--file12
--file13
--innerinnerDir1
---file111
-innerDir2
--file21
```

shows that file1, file2, innderDir1, and innderDir2 are all in the directory dir1. file11, file12, file13,  and innerinnerDir1 are all in the directory innderDir1.

The filepath "dir1/" is clearly the shortest path, where "dir1/innerDir1/innerinnerDir1/file111" is clearly the longest path (measured by length of the string).

From my work, I understand this is a tree problem, specifically a directory tree problem. So, I was trying 2 recursive methods: one that finds the max, one that finds the min.

However, I can't quite figure out how. Having the "-" determine which dirs/files are in which directories is confusing me. I also have a basic tree structure implemented (see code below). How can I build the tree given the string? Should I not worry about building the tree and then traversing it, and instead just try to find the min and max without using a Tree structure?

Tree code:

```
public class Tree<T> {
    private Node<T> root;

    public Tree(T rootData) {
        root = new Node<T>();
        root.data = rootData;
        root.children = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
    }

    public static class Node<T> {
        private T data;
        private Node<T> parent;
        private List<Node<T>> children;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is "dir1" by itself a complete path? It seems odd to ask about the shortest path if the answer is always just the root of your tree...

Comment: Sorry, thanks for asking for that clarification. We are trying to find the smallest path not including the root.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void doit(){
    String data = "dir1-file1-file2-innerDir1--file11  
    --file12--file13--innerinnerDir1---file111-innerDir2--file21";

    System.out.println("Smallest -> " + findSmallest(data));
    System.out.println("Largest -> " + findLargest(data));

}

public String findSmallest(String data){

    return new StringTokenizer(data,"-").nextToken();

}

public String getDelimiter(int value){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < value; i++){

        sb.append("-");
    }


    return sb.toString();

}


public String findLargest(String data){

    int depth = 0;      

    while (data.indexOf(getDelimiter(++depth)) != -1);

    depth-=1;       
    String value = data.substring(data.indexOf(getDelimiter(depth)) + depth);       
    return value.substring(0, value.indexOf(getDelimiter(1)));


}
```